# AWS CLI check if a lambda function exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

How do I do a one-time check if a lambda function exists via the CLI? I saw this `function-exists` option - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/wait/function-exists.html

But it polls every second and returns a failure after 20 failed checks. I only want to check once and fail if it isn't found. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why not try `aws lambda get-function --function-name abc`. This will return ResourceNotFoundException if the function does not exist.

Comment: Either what @krishna_mee2004 suggested or you can list your functions to loop through and find a function if it exists, etc. ```aws lambda list-functions```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check the exit code of `get-function` in bash. If the function does not exist, it returns exit code `255` else it returns `0` on success.
e.g.

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name my_lambda
echo $?
```

And you can use it like below:
(paste this in your terminal)

```
function does_lambda_exist() {
  aws lambda get-function --function-name $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then
    echo "Lambda '$1' exists"
  else
    echo "Lambda '$1' does not exist"
  fi
}

does_lambda_exist my_lambda_fn_name
```

Comment: Simple. Thanks @Nirdosh

Comment: my exit code showed up as 254 now on failure lols.

Comment: another way is to use `function-exists` CLI command as described here: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/wait/function-exists.html

Comment: In my case its not responding anything, I wanted to return the value instead of echo so I have returned $? but it doesn't work